# TransformedDistribution of normal and skew-normal distributions

Tags: probability-or-statistics

I have the following distributions:

```
distC =NormalDistribution[251.563, 0.317394]
distS =SkewNormalDistribution[252.973, 0.503173, 5.59741]
```

I want to analyse what results when distS-distC is used. I made the following approach:

```
gapFkt[d_] := 
 PDF[TransformedDistribution[
   s - c, {c \[Distributed] distC, s \[Distributed] distS}], d]
```

When I try to plot it, it takes veeery long. So I tried to make some points first using a table.

```
pkt = ParallelTable[gapFkt[d], {d, 0., 2., .1}]
```

This is very slow as well and all the values are 0. , although at ~1. there is a peak of ~0.8. I can use a numerical approach. However, is there a way to do it without numerical brute force?

Comment: `tdist = TransformedDistribution[s - c, {c \[Distributed] distC, s \[Distributed] distS}];` Apparently `PDF[tdist,x]` is given a value of zero rather than a distribution. Looks like a bug since it should have a valid PDF (see `RandomVariate[tdist, 10000] // Histogram`).

Comment: I don't think it's exactly a fixable bug in that there is (I think) no closed-form for the pdf.  If one tries smaller means (but with the same mean difference), just the expression is returned rather than a zero:  `distC = NormalDistribution[0, 0.317394]; distS = SkewNormalDistribution[252.973 - 251.563, 0.503173, 5.59741]; gapFkt[d_] := PDF[TransformedDistribution[s - c, {c \[Distributed] distC, s \[Distributed] distS}], d]
gapFkt[2]`.  One might need to compute the cdf numerically followed by the pdf.

Answer (score 2):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

distC = NormalDistribution[251.563, 0.317394] // Rationalize;

distS = SkewNormalDistribution[252.973, 0.503173, 5.59741] // 
   Rationalize[#, 0] &;

SeedRandom[1234]

With[{n = 25000}, data =
   RandomVariate[distS, n] -
    RandomVariate[distC, n]];

distD = FindDistribution[data, RandomSeeding -> 1234]

(* MixtureDistribution[{0.574031, 
  0.425969}, {NormalDistribution[1.60781, 0.334762], 
  GammaDistribution[26.8782, 0.0793163]}] *)

Show[
 Histogram[data, Automatic, "PDF"],
 Plot[PDF[distD, d], {d, Min@data, Max@data}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here are two ways to get a good approximation of the density with one of the ways being about as parsimonious as you can get:  numerical approximation and fit a skew normal with the same mean, variance, and skewness (method of moments).

A brute-force definition of the pdf of the difference at a value $z$ is defined to be

```
Integrate[PDF[distC, x] PDF[distS, z + x], {x, -∞,∞}]
```

But there is no closed-form solution.  Next one attempts to use numerical integration for particular values of $z$:

```
NIntegrate[PDF[distC, x] PDF[distS, 2 + x], {x, -∞,∞}]
```

But here one gets 0. for probably all values of $z$.  The fix is just to numerically integrate over the range of values of $x$ that cover most of the positive density.  Here is a table of values using that technique:

```
xLow = 251.563 - 4*0.317394
xHigh = 251.563 + 4*0.317394
pdf = Table[{z, NIntegrate[PDF[distC, x] PDF[distS, z + x], {x, xLow, xHigh}]}, 
  {z, 0, 4, 0.01}]
```

It is not unreasonable to think that maybe that a linear combination of a normal and a skew normal might have approximately a skew normal distribution.  So we find the parameters of a skew normal distribution that has the same mean, variance, and skewness as `s - c`:

```
dist = TransformedDistribution[s - c, {s \[Distributed] distS, c \[Distributed] distC}]
{μ0, σ0, α0} = Select[{μ, σ, α} /. 
  Solve[{Mean[dist] == Mean[SkewNormalDistribution[μ, σ, α]],
  Variance[dist] == Variance[SkewNormalDistribution[μ, σ, α]],
  Skewness[dist] == Skewness[SkewNormalDistribution[μ, σ, α]]},
  {μ, σ, α}, Reals], #[[2]] > 0 &][[1]]
```

Now check this with a large random sample:

```
SeedRandom[12345];
zz = RandomVariate[distS, 100000] - RandomVariate[distC, 100000];

(* Plot them all *)
Show[Histogram[zz, "FreedmanDiaconis", "PDF"],
 Plot[{pdf[z], PDF[SkewNormalDistribution[μ0, σ0, α0], z]}, {z, 0, 4},
   PlotStyle -> {{Thickness[0.02], LightGray}, Red},
   PlotLegends -> {"Numerical integration", "Skew normal approximation"}]]
```

[image: Histogram, numerical approximation, and skew normal approximation]